# Interpolation of volatility curve for Swaption

Tags: volatility, swaption, black

I have found volatility in the black model for swaption for different maturity (1-2-3-6-9M, 1Y, 18M, 2-10Y, 15-20-25-30Y) and Tenor (1-10Y, 15-20-25-30Y). Now I need another values (Maturity: 2, Tenor: 12).

I work with Excel without add-ins, I tried linear interpolation between (2,10) and (2,15), but I have some doubt on this method. I know some advanced inteprolation techniques (spline) in 2 dimension wich I could use for a given maturity, but it could take some time to implement a bicubic spline interpolation method.

I could also use a (Maturity,Tenor) Interpolation, but I have some odd values for short maturity/short tenor. I would like to remove these " outliers". There is only discussion on advanced volatility interpolation for option.

What would be a reliable/fast method to interpolate Volatility(Maturity,Tenor) ?

I don't need a generic interpolation method but some suggestion on how to improve them for volatility interpolation, or a more complex interpolation method (not too complex) wich has given some good results.

Here are my data so you could see what I am doing, the graph is a 1D cubic interpolation on maturity (step 1/12) then on tenor (step 1).

[image]

Comment: I assume you need the data for calibration purposes ?

Comment: as far as I know people often just use log linear interpolation between neighbouring rates. This is at least what Brigo&Mercurio do and there work is considered a gold standard in the field

Answer (score 2):

One of the most used interpolation techniques is the cubic spline interpolation.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) you can find an overview of that, while, on [Mathworks.com](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/ref/spline.html), you can find the tutorial to implement that in Matlab directly simply by using the *spline(x,Y,xx)* command function.

It is not difficult to implement and, moreover, it gives pretty reliable results.

I never tried to interpolate options data, but, anyway, it is proved it works pretty well on the most of macroeconomic time-series.

In the case you need for interpolating in 2-d, you can use the bi-cubic interpolation technique; [Here](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/vision/ug/interpolation-methods.html#f13689) you can find an example in Matlab.

Comment: I know spline interpolation for 1D curve, is tehre anything for a surface ?

Comment: I modified the answer; I hope it suits you.

Comment: Sorry, i meant I have spline interpolation in 1D. I don't have 2D (a matlab function is not helping, I need to code it in VBA, so a source to translate would be usefull). In fact I'm lookng for specific interpolation to finance (and vol ?) not a general one. I have edited my question to make me clearer.